# Как поделить string (C#)?

Tags: c#

Есть переменная string формата
`15|11`

Как занести числа ("|" используется как табуляция) в разные переменные и форматировать в число?
Что бы можно было производить с ними мат. функции?

Например
`result = numeral1 - numeral2`

Comment: `.Split("|")`, выдаст массив, остается перевести в int (`int.Parse(...)`).

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: Что сделать? Я же вам дал конкретные методы для реализации того, что вам надо, пробовали их использовать или без попыток сразу вопрос задавать ?

Comment: третий день (4 символа)